# Use of relative path for anchor method using iText for pdf Generation

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iText for PDF generation and I create an anchor using the following code:

```
String newPath = "file:///";
newPath = newPath + completePath;
trial.setAnchor(newPath);
```

The `trial` object is of type `Chunk` and `completePath` is the path to the file I want a link to.

When I try to use a relative path, the link doesn't work. For instance `"C:\Doc\folder1\trial.xml"` works fine but when I try relative paths such as `"..\trial1.xml"` there is no link being formed, although both my PDF document and XML file are in the same folder named `"folder1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this situation:

```
C:\Doc\folder1\trial.xml
C:\Doc\folder1\my.pdf
```

And if you create a path `"..\trial1.xml"` as a reference in `my.pdf`, then you are telling the PDF that the xml file can be found here:

```
C:\Doc\trial1.xml
```

I see two errors:

1. there's a difference between `trial.xml` and `trial1.xml`, and
2. you are pointing at the wrong directory.

There may even be a third error if you are concatenating the relative path with "file:///". We should see the PDF to make sure what happens.

I've written an example named [RelativeLink](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/RelativeLink) that creates a PDF with a `Chunk` that says "Click me". If you click that `Chunk`, the XML file `data.xml` that resides in the same direction as [relative_link.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/relative_link.pdf) opens.

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Click me");
chunk.setAnchor("./" + new File(XML).getName());
document.add(chunk);
```

This doesn't work in the context of a web plugin (for obvious reasons). To see this in action, you need to download the PDF file and open it in a standalone viewer.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, it worked. The real issue was with the directory I was pointing to which your piece of code solved.