# Relative path in itext action

Tags: c#, itext

I have tried to create a relative link in a pdf file with itextsharp in c#. I have used this example (translated to C#): http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/RemoteGoToPage.

But when I open the generated pdf and click the link nothing happens. However if I change to an absolute path the link. Thanks.

My code:

```
class Program
{
    public const string DEST = "abc2.pdf";
    public const string SRC = "xyz2.pdf";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program app = new Program();

        app.createPdf(DEST);
        app.createPdf2(SRC);
    }

    public void createPdf(string dest)
    {
        Document document1 = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document1, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));

        document1.Open();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 1"));
        document1.NewPage();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 2"));
        document1.NewPage();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 3"));
        document1.NewPage();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 4"));
        document1.NewPage();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 5"));
        document1.NewPage();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 6"));
        document1.NewPage();
        document1.Add(new Paragraph("Page 7"));
        document1.Close();
    }

    public void createPdf2(string src)
    {
        Document document2 = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document2, new FileStream(src, FileMode.Create));            
        document2.Open();
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Link");
        var link = "abc2.pdf";                    //this don't work
        //var link = "c:/temp/abc2.pdf";    //this work
        chunk.SetAction(new PdfAction(link, 6));
        document2.Add(chunk);
        document2.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to the following question: [Use of relative path for anchor method using iText for pdf Generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063677/use-of-relative-path-for-anchor-method-using-itext-for-pdf-generation). This question is almost a duplicate of yours ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ./(dot slash) or /(slash) before the file as per your file location, something like this

```
var link = "./abc2.pdf";
```

or

```
var link  "/abc2.pdf";
```

Comment: As far as I know, adding a slash only (without the dot) shouldn't work as it will point at the root of the file system.